# Creating of a new object of a different class gets overriden every time it's created

Tags: oop, lua, roblox

I'm still fairly new to OOP but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
-- TestModule

testClass = {}

local thingClassModule = require(script["ThingModule"])

function testClass:new()
  setmetatable({}, self)

  self.__index  = self
  self.Thing    = thingClassModule:new(10, 15)
  self.Thing2   = thingClassModule:new(30, 70)
end

return testClass
```

the thing class module:

```
-- ThingModule

thing = {}

function thing:new(a, b)
  local obj = {}

  setmetatable(obj, self)

  self.__index = self
  self.A = a or 0
  self.B = b or 0

  return obj
end

return thing
```

The issue is that Thing gets overriden by Thing2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is not assigning `self` to the metatable of the object instead it's being assigned to the module instead, therefore it's overwriting the data instead of creating a new object.

Here's a working example of what you're trying to achieve:

```
-- Thing Class
local Thing = {}
Thing.__index = Thing

function Thing.new(a, b)
    local self = {}
    setmetatable(self, Thing)
    
    self.A = a
    self.B = b
    
    return self
end

return Thing
```

```
local Thing = require(script.Parent.Thing)

local TestClass = {}
TestClass.__index = TestClass

function TestClass.new()
    local self = {}
    setmetatable(self, TestClass)
    
    self.Thing = Thing.new(10, 15)
    self.Thing2 = Thing.new(30, 70)
    
    return self
end

return TestClass
```

You can learn more about Object-oriented through this great article:
https://devforum.roblox.com/t/all-about-object-oriented-programming/8585

Answer (score 0):

In a method, `self` is whatever comes before the colon in the method call. In `thing.new`, you create a new table called `obj`, but you then assign `A` and `B` within `self`, which is the `thing` table (or `thingClassModule`; they're both the same table). In `testClass.new`, you set the metatable of a new table, but you don't store it to a variable. You then go on to modify `self`, which is `testClass`.